# How to create list dynamically in pdfmake

Tags: angular, pdf-generation, frontend, pdfmake

I am trying to create a list of Q&A in pdf using **pdfmake** in an angular application. I am setting the Q&A section in the following pattern:

```
{

text: 
    this.questionService.questions.
    Questions['sub-section'] 
    [0].questions[0].details['question-alt- 
    description'] + '\n', bold: true 
        },
      {
          style: 'tableExample',
          table: {
            style: 'table1',
            widths: ['*'],
            body: [
   [{ text :
    this.questionService.qanda.find(x => x.ActId == 647).ActVal == '' ? '\n' 
     : this.questionService.qanda.find(x => x.ActId == 647).ActVal === "No" ? 
      'Function for dependent question' : 'This should not print the 
        dependent question' ,
     }]
            ]
          }
      },
```

Now, the scenario is, if i select No for the above question, a dependent question should appear, otherwise it should not appear. What i have tried is below :

```
function builddependentquestion_1(data, columns) {
   const body = [];
   body.push([{
   text : 'The question i want to print',
   rowSpan: 1,
   fillColor: '#ffffff',
   bold: true,
   border: [false, false, false, false]}
   ]);

        return body;
  }

  function tabledependentquestion_1(data, columns) {
    return {
        table: {
            body: builddependentquestion_1(data, columns)
        }
    };
  }
```

And i am using the function in above ternary operator, but it is failing. Can anyone help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code examples in the first section to make it more readable.

Comment: i would advice you to separate rendering pdf code and dynamic content code.

For pdfmake rendering, you can use the playground to get the desired template http://pdfmake.org/playground.html